# How do I determine if a matrix is in a span of two other matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, span

If \begin{align}
A =\begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 1 \\
        -1 & 1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}B = \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & -1 \\
        1 & 0 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
\end{align}

So, how can I check if $C$ is in span $(A,B)$ when 
\begin{align}C=
\begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 2 \\
        3 & 4 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
\end{align}

Comment: What is the definition of span you understand?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** If you can find $κ, λ$ such that $$κ\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1\\-1&1 \end{pmatrix}+λ\begin{pmatrix}1 & -1\\1&0 \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 2\\3&4 \end{pmatrix}$$ then, the answer is yes. You have $4$ equations with $2$ unknowns, the first of the equations being $κ\cdot1+λ\cdot1=1$.

Answer (score 0):

The space of $2\times 2$ matrices is simply $\Bbb R^4$. Form a matrix with the vectors $(1,1,-1,1)$, $(1,-1,1,0)$ and $(1,2,3,4)$ and check its rank.